# CUDA memory access violation when creating an object in kernel function

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, access-violation, heap-memory

To allocate a large memory in CUDA kernel function using operator `new` I set the value of `cudaLimitMallocHeapSize` to the size of free device memory ~1.7-1.8G at every launch. But if I try to create an object in kernel function I get a memory access violation in the line `i = 42;` throwed by memory checker.
Here is the code:

```
class Test
{
private:
    int i;

public:
    __device__ Test()
    {
        i = 42;
    }
};

__global__ void test()
{
    Test *m = new Test();
    if (m == NULL)
    {
        printf("m == NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t free;
    size_t total;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&free, &total);
    cudaCheckError(cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, free));

    test << <1, 1 >> >();
    cudaCheckError(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    cudaCheckError(cudaDeviceReset());
    return 0;
}
```

But after this exception object `Test *m` is a normal object with address in device memory and with its field `i` is equal to 42.
If I remove the constructor of this class, the same exception raised in the cuda source file device_functions.h in the function

```
static __forceinline__ void* memset(void *dest, int c, size_t n)
{
  __nvvm_memset((unsigned char *)dest, (unsigned char)c, n, /*alignment=*/1);
  return dest;
}
```

If I set the heap size to 1*1024*1024*1024 = 1G - the same exception occures.

750 MB - no exception.

900 MB - no exception.

1000 MB - no exception.

1020 MB - exception.

Why it happens?
Is there any limit to heap size lower then the size of available memory?

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Nsight 4.1.
The device is GeForce GTX 650 Ti with compute capability 2.0.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPD1:** 2GB DDR5 memory total on device. OS is Windows 8.1 Professional x64.

**UPD2:** I can allocate larger then 1GB from host code using `cudaMalloc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by installing CUDA 7.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the specs of your card and it's shown to have only 1024MB of GDDR5 device memory.

So that means that if you want to have a heap of 1020MB of device memory on the card, you will have only 4MB left for the driver to use. I guess that does not work very well.

If you try with a GPU with higher amount of memory, you should be able to set a higher heap size.

---

**Edit v1**: If you have a card with a higher amount of RAM, can you try and dynamically allocate **from the host code**, a buffer that is more than 1024 MB? If you cannot do it, that may be a driver limitation.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. It seems that cudaMemGetInfo(&free, &total); always returns > 1024 MB because OS expands device memory. And heap size should be less then free device **hardware** memory. 
In official CUDA Library Documentation it is not clear:
_"Returns in *free and *total respectively, the free and total amount of memory available for allocation by the device in bytes."_

Comment: There exist versions of GTX 650 Ti that have 2GB, such as [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125446).  But it might be useful if OP clarified which card they have.  I don't think `cudaMemGetInfo` should ever report more memory than what is physically on the card.

Comment: Robert Crovella, CPU-Z shows me 2048 MB memory, maybe OS or driver limits available memory for applications?

Comment: Can you allocate from the host code a buffer on the device larger than 1020MB? I remember lower end cards having this driver limitation where you could not allocate a single buffer larger than 1/2 of the RAM on the device.

Comment: Yes, I tried to allocate 1.5G by `cudaMalloc(&p, 1.5*1024*1024*1024)` - no error. `p` has a valid device memory address.